# Stale pickling of class objects - best practice

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a basic ETL workflow that grabs data from an API, builds a class object, performs various operations which results in storing the data in applicable tables in a DB but ultimately I pickle the object and store that into the DB as well. The reason for pickling is to save these events and reuse the data for new features.

The problem is how best to implement adding attributes for new features. Of course when a new attribute is added, pickled objects are now stale and need to be checked (AttributeError, etc). This is simple with one or two changes but over time it seems like it will be problematic.

Any design tips? Pythonic best practices for inherently updating pickled objects? Seems like a common problem in database design?!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an `update` method for the class. The `update` method will take in one object of the same class *(but an older version, as you specified)* and update all the data from the object passed into the method to the new class object.

Here is an example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def add_data(self, data):
        self.data.append(data)

    def update(self, obj):
        self.data = obj.data

my_class = MyClass()
my_class.add_data(34) # Class object then gets pickled...
```

```
class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def add_data(self, data):
        self.data.append(data)
        
    def new_attr(self):
        print('This is a new attribute.')

    def update(self, obj):
        self.data = obj.data

my_class2 = MyClass2()
my_class2.update(my_class) # Remember to unpickle the class object
```